# How do I create an array whose elements are all equal to a specified value?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How do I create an array where every entry is the same value? I know `numpy.ones()` and `numpy.zeros()` do this for 1's and 0's, but what about `-1`?

For example:

```
>>import numpy as np
>>np.zeros((3,3))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

>>np.ones((2,5))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

>>np.negative_ones((2,5))
???
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if there's a nice one-liner without an arithmetic operation, but probably the fastest approach is to create an uninitialized array using `empty` and then use `.fill()` to set the values.  For comparison:

```
>>> timeit m = np.zeros((3,3)); m += -1
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.9 us per loop
>>> timeit m = np.ones((3,3)); m *= -1
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.49 us per loop
>>> timeit m = np.zeros((3,3)); m.fill(-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.31 us per loop
>>> timeit m = np.empty((3,3)); m[:] = -1
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.18 us per loop

>>> timeit m = np.empty((3,3)); m.fill(-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 us per loop
```

but to be honest, I tend to either add to the zero matrix or multiply the ones matrix instead, as initialization is seldom a bottleneck.

Comment: `100000 loops, best of 3: 9.49 us per loop` Why does this take so long ?

Comment: @Ashrj, 1. these timeings are unfortunatly not that representative, becuase the arrays is just too small, overhead for function calls plays a role (probably why its somewhat slower). 2. Actually these timings slightly change over versions, but I think using slicing (I also like `[...]`) or `.fill` are both great (and also win here). plus: *readibility counts*...

Comment: Well, `ones` is basically `empty` + `fill` with some error catching, so the only place that any performance difference *could* show up is in small array sizes, because asymptotically they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: There is now a one-liner [`np.full()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html), as per my answer below.

Answer (score 28):

Use [`np.full()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) as follows:

```
np.full((2, 5), -1.)
```

Returns:

```
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

Comment: Yep. New in numpy 1.8.0 in October 2013, which is after the accepted answer here, otherwise this would be the only answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! And what if you want different values but only for rows?

Answer (score 8):

-1 * np.ones((2,5))

Multplying by the number you need in the matrix will do the trick.

```
In [5]: -1 * np.ones((2,5))
Out[5]: 
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])

In [6]: 5 * np.ones((2,5))                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[6]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

For an array of -1s

```
-1 * np.ones((2,5))
```

Simply multiply with the constant.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
[[-1]*n]*m
```

where n is the number of columns and m is the number of rows?

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = np.repeat(10, 50).reshape((5,10))
```

Will create a 5x10 matrix of 10s.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, these are the good way to create an array with specified value

> `arr=[value for x in range(num)]`

or

> `[VALUE]*NUM`

where num is the length of Array & value is the specified value.